# How can this regex be made JavaScript compatible?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have found a regex template in Expresso, this one works fine and returns perfect matches but in JavaScript it doesn't work. I know its may be for look-behind, but I am not enough efficient in Regex to make it JS compatible.

```
\((?>[^()]+|\((?<number>)|\)(?<-number>))*(?(number)(?!))\)
```

I want to match it with ...

```
max(50, max(51, 60)) a() MAX(s,4,455)something
```

... and it should return ...

```
1: (50, max(51, 60))

2: ()

3: (s,4,455)
```

This works perfectly in Expresso but JS console in Chrome says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\((?>[^()]+|\((?<number>)|\)(?<-number>))*(?(number)(?!))\)/: Invalid group
```

How can this regex be modified to function properly in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your given regular expression is a [.NET regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx), the following syntax components are not supported by JavaScript:

- `(?>…)` – [nonbacktracking subexpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#nonbacktracking_subexpression)
- `(?<name>…)` – [named matched subexpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#named_matched_subexpression)
- `(?<name1-name2>…)` – [balancing group definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition)
- `(?(name)…)` – [conditional group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36xybswe.aspx#Conditional_Group)

To get the same result with JavaScript, you’ll need to do the balancing on your own:

```
var parts = str.match(/[()]|[^()]+/g),
    matches = [],
    balance = 0;
for (var i=0, j=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
    switch (parts[i]) {
    case "(":
        if (balance === 0) {
            j = i;
        }
        balance++;
        break;
    case ")":
        if (balance === 1) {
            matches.push(parts.slice(j, i+1).join(""));
        }
        balance--;
        if (balance < 0) {
            throw new EvalError('parentheses are not balanced; unexpected "("');
        }
        break;
    }
}
if (balance > 0) {
    throw new EvalError('parentheses are not balanced; missing ")"');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript does not support [named capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) `(?<number>)`

As suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets), regex may not be the right tool for the job. However, if you simply want to match the outermost parenthesized groups you can use this

```
/\([^)]*(\s?\))*\)/g
```

See it working at http://refiddle.co/114

Comment: Thanks Paul, it works in the given string but doesn't return expected result in different string. AVG(ROUND(5,8),10,11)*MAX(MAX(5),10,AVG(5)) Any suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, regex doesn't really handle nesting very well. You might be better off writing a tokenizer and parsing the string manually yourself instead of using regex.

Answer (score 2):

There's no negative lookbehind in Javascript. You'll have to find an alternative.

Edit: I looked at your RegEx again, and I thought I saw negative lookbehind, but I guess I didn't. I'll leave this for informational purposes anyways.

Comment: Check this link for lookbehind in JavaScript: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Comment: And there's your alternative. Thanks, Rocket.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, numbers can be defined with [0-9] or \d
Not a digit is [^0-9] or \D